# Building Maven (OSGI bundles) project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, blueprint-osgi

I am struggling to get Eclipse to think my project is compiled and works.  I inherited this project that has 23 modules (all osgi bundles) and when I run 'mvn install' it passes, but Eclipse still has red x's next to all the modules.

My ultimate goal is to be able to run this code through eclipse and debug it.  Right now I am forced to deploy this into Karaf, start it, install the features, then tear it all down when done.  This is KILLING me as it's taking so much time.

Any suggestions on how I might improve this so it doesn't take over 5 minutes to add a small little change into the code?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have maven dependencies added to your eclipse project? You can check this in Project-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries and checking if you have added Maven dependencies. if you don't see them may be your project is not being imported correctly as Maven Project

Comment: I do not see them in there.  Why would it install without any issues through the command line, but Eclipse cannot understand?

Comment: Eclipse and Maven have their own understanding of their own project structures they don't go well hand in hand though you can install M2E plugin from eclipse market place which will make your life easy.

Comment: try to add Maven dependencies by saying add libraries.

Comment: How do I say "Add libraries"?

Comment: when you go to Project-->Properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries you see a button which says "Add Library" then select Maven dependencies. If you have imported your maven project correctly then you should be able to add those from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you had some tip on how to do it programmatically.  Currently, this project makes 23 modules and I cannot manually add them each time.  That would take as long as it does now.  I hate the Java/Maven/Eclipse/ServiceMix combination!

Comment: Dan, if you check out a pristine set of the modules from the repository, how does Eclipse identify them? As maven projects, as simple java projects, or as bundles?

Comment: Since I am using git and I tell it they're Java projects, it treats them as Java projects.  I then add the "Maven-ify" it after